# ansible - replace a string or word in existing line without replace all the line

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to replace only the home directory for jenkins user in passwd, I guess `lineinfile` not good for this, because it will replace all the line and I need to keep the User ID and Group ID, for example:

current line: `jenkins:x:1002:1002::/home/jenkins:/bin/bash`

change to: `jenkins:x:1002:1002::/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash`

> /home/jenkins -> /var/lib/jenkins

```
- name: Set the Jenkins home directory in passwd
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/passwd
    regexp: '^jenkins=.*'
    line: '?'
  register: jenkins_passwd
  notify: restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match

```
^(jenkins:.:\d+:\d+::)[^:]*
```

Replace by

```
\1/var/lib/jenkins
```

This matches the start of a correctly formatted line of `/etc/passwd` up to its home directory. The informations we wish to keep are grouped in a capturing group, which stops before the current home directory definition. To replace, we reference that group then add our new home directory definition. The end of the line is left unchanged.

Comment: You could have also had a go at the regex yourself, lineinfile will do what you need. No point in missing out on all that regex fun! https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Match

> ::.*jenkins

Replace with

> ::/var/lib/jenkins